# wallet-adapter/react-ui build with the nextjs-starter app throws a can't find module error

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

error when using local build of @solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui
[image]

### reproduction steps -

```
git clone https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter .
pnpm i
pnpm build
```

in _app.tsx of the nextjs-starter app change line 3

```
import { WalletModalProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
```

to use the local build output

```
import { WalletModalProvider } from '../../../../ui/react-ui';
```

run next app

```
cd packages/starter/nextjs-starter
pnpm dev
```

Comment: You can't just use local paths like that _especially_ in a pnpm project which has strict dependency resolution. Why are you changing that path anyway?

Comment: i'm facing the same issue when using all imports from local paths. i changed the path here so it's easy to replicate

Answer (score 1):

Your Stack Exchange post *really* doesn't explain what you are trying to achieve. In general, just posting an error without any context isn't very helpful.

It *sounds* like you are attempting to reference files outside of a workspace project directory, perhaps in some other project entirely, for the purpose of modifying those files. This is strictly invalid with pnpm (and with the project's TypeScript config).

Try this:

```
git clone https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter --depth=1
cd wallet-adapter
pnpm install
pnpm build
```

This should succeed, building all packages in the workspace. If you intend to modify the workspace's `react-ui` package, you can do so.

First, go into the `nextjs-starter` project's package.json, and change the version of the `react-ui` package to `workspace:^`. Then run `pnpm install` from the root directory.

This will change the `nextjs-starter` project's dependencies to use your local workspace files for `react-ui` instead of the published npm version. Then, run this in one terminal:

```
pnpm watch
```

This will build all your workspace packages in watch mode.

Run this in a second terminal:

```
cd packages/starter/nextjs-starter
pnpm dev
```

This will run the Next.js dev server. Change something in your workspace `react-ui` package. It will change live in your running Next.js app.